# Remove last new line character of text file in batch

Tags: batch-file, newline, forfiles

I have a directory with nany text files, each containing an URL. I want to write each URL including a new line character to a text file.
Therefore I created two batch files:

job.bat:

```
@echo off
forfiles /m *.m3u /c "cmd /c output.bat @file"
```

output.bat:

```
@echo off
type %1 >> urls.txt
echo. >> urls.txt
```

When I run job.bat all URLs are written to the text file.

But there is one problem: At the end of the text file there will be a new line at the end of the text file, even if no further line will follow. What can I do to remove the new line character at the end of urls.txt?

urls.txt should look like this:
[image: urls.txt]

That's how job2.bat looks like:
[image: job2bat]

I'm not able to insert a screenshot of urls.txt, since it needs to be scrolled. But I can tell you, that it contains all URLS, one after another without being seperated by any space or new line character.

The exact .m3u files can be found [on a subpage of the homepage of a German radio station](https://www.ffh.de/musik/webradios/stream-adressen.html) (ending with .m3u). Therefore I do not include any screenshot of a m3u file.

Comment: Change the code of `job.bat` to `@(for %%I in (*.m3u) do @for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%J in ("%%I") do @echo(%%J)>urls.txt`. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. The usage of `"usebackq delims= eol="` with the `for /F` options enclosed in double quotes is not possible in this case as it would result in `"` being interpreted as end of line character. Therefore the alternate syntax with escaping space and equal sign is required to define no char as eol.

Comment: This code works for `*.m3u` files with just one or with multiple URLs. It does not matter if the last line in file has a line termination or there is no line ending at end of file. Empty lines in the `*.m3u` files are also ignored because of `for /F` always ignores them. The only requirement is that the `*.m3u` files must contain text with a character encoding using one byte per character or UTF-8 without BOM. UTF-16 encoded files are not supported by this code.

Comment: What would be the point of not having a `CRLF` at the end of the last non-empty line of the file?

Comment: I thought there must be a way in order to programmatically supress the CRLF after the last line of the created text file.

Comment: Now answer my previous question.  What is the reason that you do not need a `CRLF` at the end of the last non-empty line of the file.  I have been programming for 42 years and I always tell my clients that you have to help me understand the reason for a programming change so that I can make sure they understand the ramifications of that change.

Comment: My reason is I do not want to manually remove the new line character at the end of the file,, when no further line follows, I want to automate that.

Comment: I want to know the technical reason why it has to be removed.  I can tell you in my line of work not having that CRLF at the end of the last line causes a lot of issues down stream with our applications.

Comment: Technically it has to be removed, since there is no further line after it.

Comment: Please explain the 'technical' reason, _because I cannot think of a good one myself_, and that is exactly why @Squashman has asked. It appears to me as if there is no good reason to remove a line terminator, unless there is a future task of appending one or more characters to that same last line at some later time, _(and that would not match the syntax/structure of the previous lines)_.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm It is default for text files on Windows that every line in such a text file has as line ending a carriage return + line-feed pair. It is possible to have a text file with multiple lines on which there is no carriage return + line-feed pair at end of the text file. From a programmers point of view that file has a __string__ at end of file and not a __line__. Programs have to special handle the use case that a text file does not have a line ending at end of the file.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm There are lots of programs which have a problem to process correct a text file with a __string__ at end of file and not a __line__ because of the missing line ending at end of the file. Text editors like Notepad++ and UltraEdit have an option in the menus to display the line endings with a character like `¶` for a carriage return + line-feed pair. A text file ending with just one `¶` (CRLF) is 100% correct. Text editors allow to append text at end of file. For that reason it is possible to position the caret after CRLF at end of the file which is in text editor a new line.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm That looks like for a beginner in text editing with a text editor that the file would have an empty line at end. That is not the case. The file ends with a line which has a line ending as every text file should have at the end. The text editor just must make it possible for a user to enter text which is appended at end of the opened file and for that reason the user has the possibility to set the caret in a new line beyond end of file having a line ending at the end. The single line posted by me works 100% correct as it produces a 100% correct text file with CRLF at the end.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm The command __COPY__ can be used to copy the file contents of multiple files together to s single file like `copy /B file1.m3u + file2.m3u + "File 3.m3u" urls.txt`. That works fine for text files which have a line ending at end of the file as text files should have by convention not defined explicitly in a standard. But if the text files have no line termination at end of the file for the last line in the file, this simple and fast command line does not work and a complex solution like the posted command line with two __FOR__ loops is necessary to produce a 100% correct file.

Comment: @NorbertWillhelm In other words what you want - a file `urls.txt` with last url in file not terminated with CRLF - is in real problematic for further processing the file with Windows commands, executables or scripts. I could not read in all your comments why you don´t want a CRLF at end of `urls.txt` for a really technical reason as asked by Compo and Squashman. There are lots of text files with no line ending at end of the file. But that is most often the cause of a user who did not hit RETURN after writing the last line or a programmer has not good coded a program producing a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just a few files, *(limited by the string length of the urls with regards maximum size of the variable environment)*, and your urls do not contain `!` characters, *(which would be deleted)*, you may get away with something like this:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do Set "cr=%%G" & (Set lf=^
% 0x0A %
)
Set "fl=" & For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type *.m3u') Do If Not Defined fl (
    Set "fl=%%G") Else Set "fl=!fl! %%G"
If Defined fl Set /P "=%fl: =!cr!!lf!%" 0<NUL 1> "urls.txt"
```

---

If your files do not contain line terminators or line endings, which I've determined, seems to be consistent, you could just replace a different character or sequence of characters instead:

```sh
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F %%G In ('Copy /Z "%~f0" NUL') Do Set "cr=%%G" & (Set lf=^
% 0x0A %
)
Set "fl=" & For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type *.m3u') Do Set "fl=%%G"
If Defined fl Set /P "=%fl:3http:=3!cr!!lf!http:%" 0<NUL 1> "urls.txt"
```

Comment: All URL's @Norbert are placed into a single string separated by spaces, which are disallowed in a URL, the spaces are then replaced by a CRLF pair. I took the code directly from a batch file I already have in my collection, which I know works, _(because only those in my collection are proven to work)_. If I get chance to try it on a Windows PC some time, _(because I don't own one or have a text editor which visibly shows line endings)_, I will update. I do however have available a file which was generated using that code and it shows in hex as having 0x0D0x0A on each line, except for the last.

Comment: Yes, but it is mine.

Comment: Hi everyone, how can I change this code to remove only the last new line of my csv file? I tried the first code and it puts new lines after a whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of testing I am just using 3 urls each in a separate m3u file.

Take the following pseudo compiled code and save it as a .bat file.  Place the bat file in the same folder as the m3u files.

```
@echo off&(if defined @lo@ goto ¡)&setlocal disableDelayedExpansion&for /f "delims=:. tokens=2" %%A in ('chcp') do set "@chcp@=chcp %%A>nul"&chcp 708>nul&set ^"@args@=%*"
set "@lo@= !#$&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~""
set "@hi@=%=%¡%=%¢%=%¤%=%¥%=%§%=%¨%=%©%=%ª%=%«%=%¬%=%­%=%®%=%¯%=%°%=%±%=%²%=%³%=%´%=%µ%=%¶%=%·%=%¸%=%¹%=%º%=%»%=%¼%=%½%=%¾%=%¿%=%À%=%Á%=%Â%=%Ã%=%Ä%=%Å%=%Æ%=%Ç%=%È%=%É%=%Ê%=%Ë%=%Ì%=%Í%=%Î%=%Ï%=%Ð%=%Ñ%=%Ò%=%Ó%=%Ô%=%Õ%=%Ö%=%×%=%Ø%=%Ù%=%Ú%=%Û%=%Ü%=%Ý%=%Þ%=%ß%=%à%=%á%=%â%=%ã%=%ä%=%å%=%æ%=%ç%=%è%=%é%=%ê%=%ë%=%ì%=%í%=%î%=%ï%=%ð%=%ñ%=%ò%=%ó%=%ô%=%õ%=%ö%=%÷%=%ø%=%ù%=%ú%=%û%=%ü%=%ý%=%þ%=%ÿ%=%£%=%"
(setlocal enableDelayedExpansion&for /l %%N in (0 1 93) do set "!@hi@:~%%N,1!=!@lo@:~%%N,1!")&cmd /c ^""%~f0" !@args@!"
%@chcp@%&exit /b
:¡
%Á%%æ%%ä%%é%%ð%%¡%%ð%%ç%%ç%
%ô%%æ%%õ%%í%%ð%%ä%%â%%í%%¡%%æ%%ï%%â%%ã%%í%%æ%%å%%æ%%í%%â%%ú%%æ%%å%%æ%%ù%%ñ%%â%%ï%%ô%%ê%%ð%%ï%
%ô%%æ%%õ%%¡%%£%%í%%ê%%ï%%æ%%¾%%£%
%©%
    %ç%%ð%%ó%%¡%%%%Ê%%¡%%ê%%ï%%¡%%©%%«%%¯%%î%%´%%ö%%ª%%¡%%å%%ð%%¡%%©%
        %ç%%ð%%ó%%¡%%°%%Ç%%¡%%£%%ö%%ô%%æ%%ã%%â%%ä%%ì%%ò%%¡%%å%%æ%%í%%ê%%î%%ô%%¾%%£%%¡%%%%Ë%%¡%%ê%%ï%%¡%%©%%£%%%%ÿ%%Ê%%£%%ª%%¡%%å%%ð%%¡%%©%
            %Ê%%Ç%%¡%%Å%%Æ%%Ç%%Ê%%Ï%%Æ%%Å%%¡%%í%%ê%%ï%%æ%%¡%%æ%%ä%%é%%ð%%¡%%¢%%í%%ê%%ï%%æ%%¢%
            %ô%%æ%%õ%%¡%%£%%í%%ê%%ï%%æ%%¾%%%%ÿ%%Ë%%£%
        %ª%
    %ª%
    %ô%%æ%%õ%%¡%%°%%ñ%%¡%%£%%¯%%¾%%¢%%í%%ê%%ï%%æ%%¢%%£%%½%%Ï%%Ö%%Í%
%ª%%¿%%ö%%ó%%í%%ô%%¯%%õ%%ù%%õ%
```

You should get the following output.

[image: Notepad plus capture]

Note: that is just a typo on my part with the last link.

Comment: Windows Defender detects your batch file as TrojanDropper:BAT/MalVbsDrper.C.

Comment: Sorry, I just have to ask: is it really necessary to use obfuscated code in an answer on SO?

Comment: Definitely not a trojan.  Runs on my corporate computers at work which have some pretty restrictive security software. SentinelOne

Answer (score 1):

Removing the very last line-break in a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) is not quite trivial, not only because there are several limitations that come into account (let us at this point ignore 2 [GiB](https://ss64.com/convert.html) file size limitations).

---

A core limitation is the fact that command lines, environment variables and echoed out lines are all limited to 8 KiB, so dealing with files that contain longer lines is difficult. However, if one can life with that, here is an approach that uses a [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to read the file, [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) to output each line, including the terminating line-break, but, for the very last line, with an end-of-file character (ASCII `0x1A`) inserted before the line-break; that file is then copied by [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html), which is capable of truncating the end-of-character and everything behind, eventually resulting in a file without a final line-break (if the file has got empty lines at the end, leading to multiple consecutive line-breaks, only a single one becomes removed). All this is necessary to retain the original text and to avoid issues with special characters or sequences:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~dp0list.txt" & rem // (path to the file to remove the final line-break from)
set "_CHRF=%~dp0list.chr" & rem // (path to a file that receives a end-of-file character)
set "_TMPF=%~dp0list.tmp" & rem // (path to another temporary file)

rem // Skip processing file if it does not contain a final DOS/Windows-style line-break:
for %%I in ("%_FILE%") do (
    findstr /V "$" "%%~I" > nul && (echo Skipping file `%%~nxI`.& exit /B)
    < nul set /P ="Processing file `%%~nxI`... "
)
rem // Retrieve end-of-file character:
copy /Y /A nul "%_CHRF%" > nul
for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("%_CHRF%") do set "EOF=%%I"
rem // Write to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    set "PREV="
    rem // Iterate through lines of the file (each of which must be shorter than 8 KiB):
    for /F "delims=" %%J in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Output each line but delayed by one loop iteration:
        if defined PREV (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(!PREV:*:=!
            endlocal
        )
        set "PREV=%%J"
    )
    rem // Specifically handle last line by appending an end-of-line character:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!PREV:*:=!!EOF!
    endlocal
)
rem // Copy temporary file over original one regarding the end-of-line character:
copy /Y "%_TMPF%" /A "%_FILE%" /B > nul
echo done.
rem // Clean up unneeded files:
del "%_CHRF%" "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

---

A possible way to avoid the 8 KiB line length limitation is to utilise [`certutil.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) and its [`-encodehex`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html#encodehex) verb to encode the file as a hexadecimal string, which is then read by [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and which can easily be edited since there are no more special characters; the final line-break is removed by deleting the string `0d0a` from the end of the hexadecimal string, whereupon it becomes decoded back to text using the [`-decodehex`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html#decodehex) verb of `certutil`. Unfortunately, `certutil` introduces a file size limitation of a few tens of MiB:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~dp0list.txt" & rem // (path to the file to remove the final line-break from)
set "_HEXF=%~dp0list.hex" & rem // (path to a file that receives the hexadecimal stream)
set "_TMPF=%~dp0list.tmp" & rem // (path to another temporary file)

rem // Skip processing file if it does not contain a final DOS/Windows-style line-break:
for %%I in ("%_FILE%") do (
    findstr /V "$" "%%~I" > nul && (echo Skipping file `%%~nxI`.& exit /B)
    < nul set /P ="Processing file `%%~nxI`... "
)
rem // Encode file into a hexadecimal stream (there is a size limit of few tens of MiB):
certutil -f -v -encodehex "%_FILE%" "%_HEXF%" 12 > nul
rem // Rounded up integer division; `+2` for final line-break of the hexadecimal stream:
for %%I in ("%_HEXF%") do set /A "LOOP=1+(%%~zI-1+2)/1023"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Read from hexadecimal file, write into temporary file:
< "!_HEXF!" > "!_TMPF!" (
    set "PREV=" & set "CURR="
    rem // Iterate one more time as the above integer division of the file size gives:
    for /L %%J in (0,1,%LOOP%) do (
        rem // Try to read a hexadecimal fragment:
        set /P CURR="" && (
            rem // Reading successful, hence return fragment from last iteration:
            < nul set /P ="!PREV!"
            set "PREV=!CURR!"
        ) || (
            rem // Reading failed, so end of data is reached; remove final line-break:
            if "!PREV:~-4!"=="0d0a" (
                < nul set /P ="!PREV:~,-4!"
            ) else if "!PREV:~-2!"=="0a" (
                < nul set /P ="!PREV:~,-2!" & rem // (this handles Unix-style files)
            ) else (
                < nul set /P ="!PREV!" & rem // (this should normally never be reached)
            )
        )
    )
)
endlocal
rem // Decode temporary file with reduced hexadecimal stream, overwrite original file:
certutil -f -v -decodehex "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%" 12 > nul
echo done.
rem // Clean up unneeded files:
del "%_HEXF%" "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B
```